# Almost all sites won't load in Windows 10

Tags: google-chrome, internet, firewall, anti-virus, windows-firewall

Recently my Internet has been acting badly. Basically, I can only load certain sites. Some sites work great, and others don’t load at all. I think this is because some firewall or antivirus thing.

#### How this came to be.

About 3 weeks ago, I made the upgrade to Windows 10. When this happened I was prompted to uninstall my Anti-Virus (Symantec EndPoint Protection), I was told it was incompatible (ultimately it just needed an update). I performed the uninstall knowing I could later re-install it. Once the upgrade was complete, I opened a browser and noticed many websites did not load, however I was able to reinstall the antivirus program. This didn't resolve the issue.

#### What I know.

- The sites that load all are sites that I have visited in the past.
- Not all of the sites I have visited in the past load.
- Probably not a network issue, doesn't affect other devices, and I have the same issue when I tried it on a mobile hotspot.
- Doesn't have to do with network adapter, tried it with 3 different ones, all using different drivers.
- Some sites will load but only if you get to them in weird ways, for example from a url or link only some you vids will load, but from those videos you can navigate to any YouTube video.
- Same issue on all browsers I have tested, Chrome, Edge, IE. But Chrome will load some sites that Edge wont.
- Chrome gives me “Error 138 (net::ERR_NETWORK _ACCESS_DENIED)’, chrome says it has to do with some kind of firewall

#### What I have tried.

- Disabling windows firewall and antivirus.
- Temporarily disabling SEP (AntiVirus)
- Search file contents for urls that work (in case there is some sort of whitelist) but only in file explorer.
- Running windows network troubleshooter, which says nothing is wrong.

All of these had no effect.

Comment: What sort of error do you get in the browser when the failing websites can't load?

Comment: Error 138 (net::ERR_NETWORK _ACCESS_DENIED) in chrome, IE says This page cant be Displayed, and Edge says Hmm, we can't reach this page

Comment: Has your machine been configured to use a proxy? (probably not to your knowledge, but it might be worth looking to see)

Comment: How would I check?

Comment: PC Settings > Network > Proxy (check for VPN too)

Comment: Nope nothing there.